# How to serve a simple static html page and use provided location hash

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I would like to serve a page and make use of the provided location hash so that the page scrolls down to the right spot. Since Google App Scripts puts the output into a contained iframe, the hash in the top, browser window is ignored.

My doGet() looks like this:

```
function doGet(e) {  
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(DriveApp.getFilesByName('My File.html').next().getBlob().getDataAsString());
}
```

That works and the page loads. It's a totally static page and nothing is generated at page-visitation time. Let me know if I'm missing a simple way to serve static html files from Google Drive. Now I want the page to scroll down to a specified spot on the page. The url would look something like

```
http://bit(dot)ly/myspecialwebpage#some-subject
```

which would redirect to something like

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AK...Hckf/exec#some-subject
```

I tried putting this script into the html, but it doesn't work

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    window.location.hash = window.top.location.hash
</script>
```

The top window is served from script.google.com

and the iframe is served from script.googleusercontent.com

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch. That worked!